# Can't access APEX server from another same network PC

Tags: windows, oracle, networking, virtual-machine, oracle-apex

I have Oracle APEX 5.X installed over Oracle Express DB on windows 10 on a virtual machine.

I turned off all firewalls on the guest windows 10 VM and added all outbound and inbound rules to allow connecting to Oracle APEX port 8008.

I ran execute dbms_xdb.setListenerLocalAccess(l_access => FALSE); to allow accessing the APEX server over network instead of just localhost.

**Now, What I'm able to do:**

- I can ping the guest machine IP address (192.168.100.2) from other
  PCs on the network
- I can open Oracle APEX inside the guest machine
    192.168.100.2:8080/apex

**What I can't do:**

- I can't open 192.168.100.2:8080/apex from any other PC in the same
  network. I get an error: This site can’t be reached

  192.168.100.2 refused to connect.

I searched for 5 hours now without any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved after connecting the laptop with the VM to a wired LAN connection instead of wireless.